# How do I add labels for a horizontal bar using matplotlib module?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

Since I am a newbie, please tell me how I should add labels for each bar toward the right. And it would be kind of you to explain the code too...
Thank you.

This is the dataframe that I have used:

```
   BG_donated   Qty                            Hospital   Location    Contact
0          A-    25               Badr Al Sama Hospital      Sohar   43445995
1          A+    64                     Aster Al Raffah      Saham   58939595
2          B+    41                       Ibri Hospital       Ibri   74823847
3          B-    35                     Apollo Hospital   Hamriyah   63947392
4          O-    51   Sultan Qaboos University Hospital       Seeb   95821774
5          O+    30     Al Hayat International Hospital  Al Ghubra   44721402
6         AB-    46                  KIMS Oman Hospital    Darsait   37190481
7         AB+    41   NMC Healthcare Specialty Hospital       Ruwi   92810482
```

This is the code for the horizontal bar graph:

```
y = df3['Qty'].sort_values()
w = df3['Hospital']
c = ['coral', 'salmon', 'indianred', 'brown', 'crimson', 'aquamarine',  
     'lightseagreen', 'slategray']
mplt.title('Analysis Report I',size = 30)
mplt.xlabel('Amount of Blood Donated',size = 15)
mplt.ylabel('Hospitals',size = 15)
mplt.barh(w,y,color = c)
mplt.show()
```

And this is the output:

[image]

Here is what I want it to look like:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this?
[image]

If so,add "for i,values in enumerate(y):

```
           mplt.text(values, i, '%s' %values)" to your code.
```

Comment: but what to do if i want add the blood groups as the label for each bar?

Comment: For "but what to do if i want add the blood groups as the label for each bar? " ,I'm not sure what you really want, can you draw sth to illustrate your point?

Comment: I have included a picture of what I want it to look like in the question please check it

Comment: The same, I give u the whole code
y = df3['Qty'].sort_values()
w = df3['Hospital']
b = df3['BG_donated']
c = ['coral', 'salmon', 'indianred', 'brown', 'crimson', 'aquamarine',  
     'lightseagreen', 'slategray']
mplt.title('Analysis Report I',size = 30)
mplt.xlabel('Amount of Blood Donated',size = 15)
mplt.ylabel('Hospitals',size = 15)
mplt.barh(w,y,color = c)

for i,values in enumerate(y):
    mplt.text(values, i, f"{b[i]}")
mplt.show()

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still not getting it. It's showing an error...                                           
It says undefined name b for ' for i,values in enumerate(y): mplt.text(values, i, f"{b[i]}") '

Comment: Add  to your code :

b = df3['BG_donated']  #get values of df3['BG_donated']

for i,values in enumerate(y)
    : mplt.text(values, i, f"{b[i]}")   # b[i] ：Iterate through b

Answer (score 0):

```
y = df3['Qty'].sort_values()
w = df3['Hospital']
b = df3['BG_donated']
c = ['coral', 'salmon', 'indianred', 'brown', 'crimson', 'aquamarine',  
    'lightseagreen', 'slategray']
mplt.title('Analysis Report I',size = 30)
mplt.xlabel('Amount of Blood Donated',size = 15)
mplt.ylabel('Hospitals',size = 15)
mplt.barh(w,y,color = c)

for i,values in enumerate(y):
    mplt.text(values, i, f"{b[i]}")
mplt.show()
```